# Storing MySQL Connection String in Variables from User Input then Building String [C#]

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I am using a form where the user inputs the database connection information, it is then stored in multiple strings in the class `dbConStr` then built and referenced from the actual connection form.

Here is the class file:

```
class dbConStr
{
    public static String strServer;
    public static String strPort;
    public static String strDatabase;
    public static String strUid;
    public static String strPwd;

    public static String strConnect = strServer + strPort + strDatabase + strUid + strPwd;
}
```

Here is the button that assigns the values to the Strings:

```
    private void btnStoreCon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbConStr.strServer = "Server="+txtServer.Text+";";
        dbConStr.strPort = "Port=" + txtPort.Text + ";";
        dbConStr.strDatabase = "Database=" + txtDatabase.Text + ";";
        dbConStr.strUid = "Uid=" + txtUsername.Text + ";";
        dbConStr.strPwd = "Pwd=" + txtPassword.Text + ";";
    }
```

The error I am receiving is that is unable to connect to the specified MySQL host.

Comment: I hope you realize that 'public static' means that at any given time, the last provided value to any of those strings will be the value any and all users see. In other words, this can not be trusted for several different users accessing different databases simultaneously.

Comment: And what is the resulting connection string?

Comment: So - are you asking about the "unable to connect to the specified MySQL host" problem or about storing parts of connection string? If the problem is in the connection - attach the exact error message or exception info

Comment: Server and port number should be in format server=hostNameOrIp:portNumber;

Comment: Sorry i was thinking about SQL Server. For MySQL please refer to this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html. Apparently it will ignore the port value if your mysql db is using unix socket

Comment: @cyberhubert I have solved it. Look at my answer, it was a problem with creating the connection string.

Comment: that's good point :) However, consider using the connection string builder - they are pretty clever and usable beasts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySqlConnectionStringBuilder to create connection string.

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
conn_string.Server = "localhost";
conn_string.UserID = "user";
conn_string.Password = "password";
conn_string.Database = "test_db";
var connectionString = conn_string.ToString();
```

Or try something like this:

```
class dbConStr
{
    public static String strServer;
    public static String strPort;
    public static String strDatabase;
    public static String strUid;
    public static String strPwd;

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        conn_string.Server = dbConStr.strServer;
        conn_string.UserID = dbConStr.strUid;
        conn_string.Password = dbConStr.strPwd;
        conn_string.Database = dbConStr.strDatabase;
        conn_string.Port = dbConStr.strPort;

        return conn_string.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: In theory your answer is correct but I fail to see how this would fix the problem _unable to connecti to the specified host_

Comment: this is more complex way to create connection string that is recommended to use.

Comment: also you can ovveride ToString() method of dbConStr class to return this kind of connectionString

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;






    private void btnStoreCon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection;
        string server;
        string database;
        string uid;
        string password;

        server = txtServer.Text;
        database = txtDatabase.Text;
        uid =  txtUsername.Text;
        password =txtPassword.Text;
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

more can be found in here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnStoreCon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbConStr.strServer = "Server=" + txtServer.Text + ";";
        dbConStr.strPort = "Port=" + txtPort.Text + ";";
        dbConStr.strDatabase = "Database=" + txtDatabase.Text + ";";
        dbConStr.strUid = "Uid=" + txtUsername.Text + ";";
        dbConStr.strPwd = "Pwd=" + txtPassword.Text + ";";

        dbConStr.strConnect = dbConStr.strServer + dbConStr.strPort + dbConStr.strDatabase + dbConStr.strUid + dbConStr.strPwd;
    }
```

I needed to create the string within the button click event